# Iterate through array of ids in Observable and add data from each id query to the same object

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have a "Group" document which contains an array of "Member" IDs. The data for each "Member" is stored in another "users" collection. For every ID in the array I want to fetch the user data and add it to the original group object. The desired output should look like:

```
{
 name: "Group 1",
 members: ["id1", "id2", "id3"],
 membersData: [
  { id: "id1", name: "Max", img: "..." },
  { id: "id2", name: "Peter", img: "..." },
  { id: "id3", name: "John", img: "..." },
 ]
}
```

this is what my function looks like right now:

```
this.groupService
      .getById(this.user.currentGroup)
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((group: IGroup) => {
          return forkJoin(
            group.members.map((member: any) =>
              this.userService.getById(member).pipe(
                take(1),
                map((userData: PublicUser) => ({ ...group, userData })),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
      )
      .subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```

and the current output looks like this:

```
[{
 name: "Group 1",
 members: ["id1", "id2", "id3"],
 membersData: { id: "id1", name: "Max", img: "..." },
},
{
 name: "Group 1",
 members: ["id1", "id2", "id3"],
 membersData: { id: "id2", name: "Peter", img: "..." },
},
{
 name: "Group 1",
 members: ["id1", "id2", "id3"],
 membersData: { id: "id3", name: "John", img: "..." },
}]
```

the problem is that when I use the spread syntax to combine the group and user data, I get a new object for every user that gets fetched instead of one group object where every user data is story in the membersData array. I know that I can't use the spread syntax here but I just can't figure out how to adjust the function to get the desired behavior. Every advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Inside of the mergeMap function, I would: 1) define a variable "result" that will store the end result, 2) use "tap" instead of "map" and simply update this variable rather than return a new object with the spread operator, 3) add a "pipe(map(...)) " on the forkJoin itself to return that variable. This way, the variable is created once every time getById emits a value, and simply updated once per member.

Comment: @NicolasB damn I already had the const but I was really just missing the .pipe(map()) on the forkJoin itself to return the complete object. Now the code works as intended. Thank you!